# How to export MySQL works that works in all version

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

After upgrade of apache version (5.6.12) to the latest mysql returns duplicate errors importing dump files.

The simple question is that how to export the mysql dump file that works in all php mysql and mysql.

- Importing File to : Server version: 5.5.27 - MySQL Community Server (GPL).
- Exporting File From : Server version: 5.5.44-37.3-log - Percona    Server (GPL).

Comment: Tool(s) used for import and export?

Comment: If server package does not allow mysql shell ( if incase)

Comment: MySQL 5.6 and 5.5 shouldn't be treating uniqueness constraints differently. Likewise, 5.5 to 5.5 should not have these issues. Are you sure the target database is empty before you start?

Comment: @tadman yes i checked database is empty

Comment: I am not familiar with phpmyadmin, but does the database have triggers? (If so, could you backup and restore the triggers separately.)

Comment: Windows MySQL front works performed well ... no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Matter what your Server version is you can use

> [mysql shell](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html)

The command

```
mysql -uroot -ppass DATABASE_NAME < /your/path/to/dump.sql
```